# Wall of Flesh Glitch or Bug

Tags: terraria-console

When I summoned the Wall of Flesh, it came with no eyes, mouth or Hungry, but the Wall still gave the tounge Debuff, how to I get rid of this bug or glitch or avoid it? This is also Wii U 1.2.4.1 desktop or better known as 1.08 update.

Sorry, I can't get a screenshot, but I can tell you that I would summon it the regular way you would summon the Wall of Flesh.

Comment: I don't the awnser to this, but I do know this shouldn't happen at all.

Comment: I'm also playing a Old Gen Console.

Comment: Can you close the world and reload it?

Comment: I tried, but then I got the glitche 4 more times

Comment: Lsoot, could you edit in some more details? The more details you give, like the exact game version, the more likely someone can help you.

Comment: Okay, let me think

Comment: It'd probably help if there was a screenshot or something, but not sure how well that would work.  How did you summon the wall?  The more details you can give, the better the chance you'll get an answer.  What you have now doesn't really provide much to help answerers.

Comment: Just same old way you would summon the Wall of Flesh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Wall of Flesh is summoned by the voodoo doll of the Guide falling into the lava in the Underworld.
The bug you are describing is a [known problem](https://terraria.fandom.com/wiki/Wall_of_Flesh#Bugs), and can happen when the doll's destruction happens too far away from the player(s) (e.g. offscreen).

Instead of killing the Voodoo Demon holding the doll and having the Guide doll tumble down, try just gathering the doll and dropping it into the lava manually.
This *should* solve the issue.